# How to play external Video with Air for iOS

Tags: ios, video, air, mp4, flv

I'm writing a small video app. Basically, you can select 12 videos in the app, press a button, and the selected video starts playing.

I do this with StageVideo and on the desktop, while testing, everything works fine. The video starts instantly, even as he is on a webserver. (Note, I tried a mp4 and a flv version.)

But as soon as I publish, the video won't play on the iPhone. Am I missing some Apple security  issues about loading external content?

Thank you for your help.

N

Comment: Can you play the video through Safari? Do you have render mode set to GPU or Direct?

Comment: Render Mode is GPU, and yes, if I just put the path in Safari, the video plays. It also plays on the desktop e.g. the path is correct.

Comment: That is Safari on the iOS device, correct? And can you hear sound or is there nothing there at all? You also need to make sure that the server serving up the video supports the "Range" HTTP header as well as responds with the "Accept-Range" header. It also must be an h.264 encoded MP4 video, preferably encoded with Handbrake's "Web Optimized", or similar, option which puts the metadata at the beginning of the video rather than the end.

Comment: Hi Josh, yes, its safari on the iPhone 5. No, no sound nothing. It is h264 mp4.

Comment: I did some more tests, and just found out, that I get: NetStream.Play.Failed, which isnt really a help in the Adobe Air Reference. It looks like it finds the path, but cannot play the movie?????

Comment: Just a quick one, it must be also encoded with AAC, not mp3. Also, have you looked at the video profile. It should be baseline rather than main for mobiles, although main will work on some devices.

Comment: What do you mean by 'external'? Where ARE the videos that you can't play on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an Adobe issue?
check out this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/red5interest/mU9oCL_RpAQ

Answer (score 0):

If you are on iOS 7 your videos will have to be on an https:// server.

Comment: I tested it, no positive results

Comment: Ok, let's see your code, and a screen shot of your publish settings.